# sonarLint: Invoke method(s) only conditionally

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I have this piece of code:

```
logger.error("Unauthorized error: {} with request {} from {} ",
        authException.getMessage(),
        request.getServletPath(),
        getClientIp(request));
```

and:

```
  private static String getClientIp(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String remoteAddr = "";

        if (request != null) {
            remoteAddr = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
            if (remoteAddr == null || "".equals(remoteAddr)) {
                remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();
            }
        }

        return remoteAddr;
    }
```

I but I have this warning:

```
 Invoke method(s) only conditionally
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `isErrorEnabled` before logging.

```java
if (logger.isErrorEnabled())
    logger.error("Unauthorized error: {} with request {} from {} ",
        authException.getMessage(),
        request.getServletPath(),
        getClientIp(request));
```